# Android find language and set Fontface in android

Tags: android

Json array will contain list of string data. Each elements of the JsonArray in different language.How to find that language and set fontface in android.

For example ["tamil-font data","english - font - data","Hindi data"] like this.

Answer (score 0):

1. About finding the language, I would recommend to add an indicator to the JSON.
2. About font face, make sure you have all font that you need:
   2.1 Place the font to assets folder.
   2.2 Any View that inherits from TextView can change its font, for example:

> ```
> Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/epimodem.ttf");
> tv.setTypeface(face);
> ```

2.3 if you need to change the text style linke bold or italic use in the TextView's XML attribute:

> android:textStyle="italic" 
>  android:typeface="serif"

Tip: If need the same font more than one one time, reuse the Typface variable to avoid overhead.